# Json encode returns null value for some characters

Tags: php, mysql, json, unicode

I writed a simple php file (recalled using GET method), that returns a json file. The code follows here:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];

$query = "SELECT name, surname, data, session from users where id= ?";
      $stmt = $connectiondb->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
      $id= $q;
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($name,$surname,$data,$session);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();

      $array = array("name" => $name, "surname" => $surname,"data" => $data, "session" => $session); 
      echo json_encode($array);
```

The field "session" in the table of my database (mySql) is definied in this way:

```
Type : text
Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

I tried to launch the script selecting a row from the table "users" where session has the value `"last session"` and the result is the following:

```
{"name":"John","surname":"Mayer","date":"2013-01-01","session":"last session"}
```

and this is good. But when the filed session in my table has the value `"1° session"` the script generates the following output:

```
{"name":"Mike","surname":"Stern","date":"2013-04-02","session":null}
```

(as you can sea session is null in json output)

I think that the problem is generated by the character `°`. How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding the following line of code php:

```
$session = utf8_decode($session);
```

and I obtain this:

```
{"name":"Mike","surname":"Stern","date":"2013-04-02","session":"1? session"}
```

I have no longer the null value but the `°` is translated into `?` character.

Comment: Could you show the content of your table as returned by `SELECT * FROM users` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux If I print the variable php session it returns me "1° session"

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I'm sure this is the correct way. The variables php are all correctly created. look here http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php for the uso of bind_param

Comment: `json_encode` requires data to be UTF-8. Your **database connection** likely isn't set to UTF-8. See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: The answer in the suggested post does not solve my problem, because the character ° is translated into \u00b0 sequence and if I try to convert it to charcater using utf8_decode() I obtain null

Comment: If "°" is encoded to `\u00b0`, **that's correct!** That's perfectly fine JSON encoding for "°". You have fixed the problem! You don't need to `utf8_decode` anything.

Comment: Read about what `utf8_decode` does → [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

I add this line:

```
$connectiondb->set_charset('utf8');
```

the result is the following:

```
{"name":"Mike","surname":"Stern","date":"2013-04-02","session":"1\u00b0 session"}
```

This seems a problem cause I want ° and not the relative UTF8 code.

But, since the php file is called form ajax I simply setted

```
scriptCharset: "utf-8"
```

and now I can be refer to data.session and obtain `"1° session"`

Comment: `scriptCharset` shouldn't do anything, since the character is not UTF-8 encoded! It's *JSON escaped*. If you simply parse the JSON with a proper JSON parser, it'll be parsed and the original character restored.